# Почему Ajax запрос на массовое удаление полей не работает Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

**Мой аджакс запрос:**

```
        var users_ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'];
        $.ajax({
        url: '/users/mass_delete',
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: {
            "users_ids": users_ids,
            "_method": 'DELETE',
            "_token": token,
        },
    })
```

**Мой роут:**

```
    Route::delete('users/mass_delete', 'User_controller@mass_delete');
```

**Мой контроллер класс**

```
    public function mass_delete( Request $users_ids ){
        User::destroy( $users_ids );
}
```

**Дампы   dd($users_ids->all()) и  dd(User::all()) вернут**

```
    Collection {#302 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    0 => User {#303 ▶}
    1 => User {#304 ▶}
    2 => User {#305 ▶}
    3 => User {#306 ▶}
    4 => User {#307 ▶}
    5 => User {#308 ▶}
    6 => User {#309 ▶}
    7 => User {#310 ▶}
    8 => User {#311 ▶}
    9 => User {#312 ▶}
    10 => User {#313 ▶}
    11 => User {#314 ▶}
    12 => User {#315 ▶}
    13 => User {#316 ▶}
  ]
}

// и

array:2 [
"users_ids" => array:11 [
0 => "1"
1 => "2"
2 => "3"
3 => "4"
4 => "5"
5 => "6"
6 => "7"
7 => "8"
8 => "9"
9 => "10"
10 => "11"
]
"_token" => "vQPAR1sohP0mTpel5XbQSf8ywzv6iRx57VAxnBrM"
]
```

**Если поставить проверку в контроллере:**

```
 if ( is_array( $users_ids ) && !empty( $users_ids ) ) {
      User::destroy( $users_ids );
    } else {
      User::findOrFail( $users_ids )->delete();
    }
   }
```

**Выдаст ошибку:**

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 113:
No query results for model [App\User] DELETE /users/mass_delete HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 262
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: XSRF-...
in Handler.php line 113
at Handler->prepareException(object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Handler.php line 130
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Handler.php line 47...
...
```

Comment: User::destroy($request->input('users_ids',[])) вместо User::destroy( $users_ids );

Answer (score 0):

А если так попробовать `User::whereIn('id',$user_ids)->delete();`